# Filling out calendar with Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I want to fill out the calendar date field for www.vegas.com/lasvegastraveldeals.

So far I can't seem to get the `value` method to work.  Here is my code:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.vegas.com/lasvegastraveldeals/')
vegas_form = page.form('gs')
vegas_form.q = 'DFW'
departure = vegas_form.field_with(:id => 'departureDatec12')
departure.value = "05/16/2014"
pp page
```

I get this error:

```
vegas_scraper.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `value=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That id is being populated at runtime using JS. Thus mechanize not able to find it I think.

Comment: You need to use `watir`/`selenium`..

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field name is `departureDate` then this should work:

```
form['departureDate'] = '05/16/2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not finding the input with id `departureDatec12`. According to the source code of the page it is `departureDate2`. So try with this

```
departure = vegas_form.field_with(:id => 'departureDate2')
```

Comment: I tried it.. still not working. Did you run the code with your change ?

Comment: If you do page view source, you wouldn't find the *id*

Comment: Why not? I can see the departure input. `input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="02/25/2014" name="departureDate" id="departureDate2" ...`

Comment: Doing *view page source* or using *inspect element* ?

Comment: Inspect element with Developer Tools.

Comment: Humm.. Try with page source, what `Mechanize` also seeing. :-)

Comment: Mechanize it is a bit old, isn't? As you said, the OP should use watir/selenium. Thanks!

Comment: So watir handles javascript?  It looks alot similar to mechanize.

Comment: @Rafa, it doesn't matter whether Mechanize is old, it matters whether it's the appropriate tool for the job. If anything, its age infers it's well tested and used for a lot of applications.

Comment: Watir controls browsers, and the browsers handle JavaScript.